# É possível obrigar um método a ser estendido em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, herança, método-abstrato

É possível "obrigar" um método a ser extensível?

O enunciado do exercício fala exatamente isso: temos que criar uma classe, dentro dela criar um método e obrigar que esse método seja estendido. Pelo que entendi das coisas que li, todos os métodos poderiam ser extensíveis, cada um com as suas peculiaridades, mas o `public` é aquele que pode ser estendido com a maior liberdade, mas isso não quer dizer que seja obrigatoriamente extensível, ou não?

Existe uma forma de "obrigar" o método a ser extensível em Java?

Comment: Ajuda imensamente!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `public` não é aquele que pode ser estendido com mais liberdade, não há diferença nesse aspecto com relação a visibilidade do método.

Todos os métodos são extensíveis por padrão no Java, então não tem que fazer nada para obrigar isso, só n]ao pode colocar um `final` nele porque aí proíbe ele ser extensível.

Para obrigar um método ser **estendido** tem que fazer ele não ter implementação, portanto tem que marcá-lo como abstrato, o que obrigará a classe ser abstrata também. Não tem como obrigar de outra forma, a não ser por mecanismos externos à linguagem.

Algo assim:

```
abstract class CalculadoraBase {
    public abstract int Soma(int x, int y);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Abstract.java).

Comment: Ah sim, eu fiquei pensando nos modificadores de acesso, e nem me passou pela cabeça sobre essa possibilidade da classe abstrata.  Vou ler um pouco mais sobre. Valeu, meu caro!

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi, como assim votar em tudo?

Comment: Pode votar em todo site, mas acho que já entendeu, pelo que percebi já votou na resposta.